# Retain '?' character in slug typo3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a question regarding retaining reserved characters during slug generation in the typo3 backend.

For example, a page with the name **"How are you?"** by default the slug generator will change to the readable format like **/how-are-you**.

What I need is to retain the "?" in the URL which is a reserved character.

I have tried the percent-encoding for the "?", but the "%" gets removed on saving.

I have added the replacement for "?" => '%3F' see the below TCA configuration

`$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['slug']['config']['generatorOptions']['replacements'] = ['?' => '%3F'];`

Please let me know how the reserved characters can be retained in the slug generation.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to keep the "?" in the slug?

The question mark ("?", ASCII 3F hex) is used to delimit the boundary between the URI of a queryable object, and a set of words used to express a query on that object.

Which means that after the question mark the GET parameters begin.

See the [reserved characters documentation](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html) on w3.org